# prefix not bound error when parsing OpenXML file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-builder, openxml

I'm using the XML class of actionscript  to read and modify the OpenXML document of a Word template, for an application developed with Flashbuilder.
However, for some reason, I get stuck on this error for some Word documents(and not others):

```
TypeError: Error #1083: The prefix "v" for element "textbox" is not bound.
```

The unbound prefix changes from time to time(e.g. sometimes it's "w"). Of course, those namespaces are all defined in the document:

```
<w:document
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
```

This error happens directly when trying to construct an XML object from the XML document's string data:

```
this._document = XML(document);//'document' is the string containing the document.xml data
```

What could cause that error? I know the XML constructor has a tendency to do some automatic formatting(for example, I have to remove 'xmlns="..."' declarations that are automatically added to the xml when converting it to string), but as I said that problem is not consistent for all Word documents. Could it be a Flashbuilder issue?

Anyway, I'm kind of lost here.

Thanks.

EDIT: The problem seems to have gone away for now. I reinstalled Flashbuilder, though that did not solved the problem immediately. I had to (again) delete the bin-debug folder where I kept the .docx file, and then it ended up working.

EDIT: And now it's back again. It seems to come and go.

Comment: What exact parts `xmlns=...` are you removing? What happens if you do not remove them? On other occurrences of the error, what prefixes are unbound and how does their definition in the xml file look like?

Comment: Actionscript apparently automatically adds declarations for the 'xmlns' namespace, and that corrupts the document. So I have to remove "xmlns="..."" declarations(using regex search-and-replace on the stringified document). As I mentioned, the "w" prefix and the "v" prefix were mostly the culprits. And as you can see from the declaration header I included ,they are all defined. But as of right now, I do not have that problem any more for the word document. Although I still don't know what caused the problem, and I'm unsure as to what solved it.